# pass data response from xhr to html element

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have input element in my page, and i receive data from XMLHttpRequest when i click button.
I try to pass some data to html element, the data receive correctly but i can't pass to element.
this is my code

```
<input type="text" value="5" id="a" />

<script>
(function() {
            let origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
            let a = 0;

            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
                console.log('request started!');
                this.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    console.log('request completed!');
                    console.log(this.readyState); //will always be 4 (ajax is completed successfully)
                    console.log((JSON.parse(this.responseText)).input.a); // result = 20
                    a = parseInt((JSON.parse(this.responseText)).input.a);

                    $("#a").val(a); // not work
                    $("#a").setAttribute('value',a); // error: TypeError: $(...).setAttribute is not a function
                    document.getElementById("a").value = a; // error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
                    $("#a").value = a; // not work

                });
                origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        })();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tested *that* exact code? The error indicates that the input doesn't exist in the document at the time the load function is called … which it is in this example.

Comment: Also you never call `send()` so the request will never be sent so it will never fire a load event.

Comment: Exactly I have refactored the request to actually fire and set the data when appropriate. Please consider using modern alternatives for async requests for your own sake.

Comment: @Quentin I receive data in this line `console.log((JSON.parse(this.responseText)).input.a);` correctly. when i test out function to change value of input it work. but i can't pass data when i receive data from xmlhttprequest

Comment: @user4450367 — That has nothing to do the points I raised in my comments.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in your request. Providing you really want to use the relict that XHR is it should be refactored this way:

```
const input = document.getElementById('a');

const myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

myReq.onload = function() {
    const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    input.value = data;
};

myReq.onerror = function(err) {
    console.log(err);
};

myReq.open('get', '[your url]', true);
myReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', ' application/json');
myReq.send();
```

I have tested this code and it works with a dumb api.

Comment: "The problem is in your request" — No, it isn't. The problem is that `document.getElementById("a")` is returning `null`

Comment: Since the code in the question says `document.getElementById('a')` and your code also says `document.getElementById('a')` … I don't see why it should behave any differently. The OP's code lacks — as I pointed out in a comment — a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem so I can't test your changes against their situation but nothing about your changes strikes me as addressing that at all.

Comment: I did test that and the code works so this is meaningless. I have handled the issue, I don't know what he was doing before and why it was null. What I know is that with his exact HTML and this exact JS this is working..

Comment: If you don't know why `document.getElementById('a')` was returning `null` in the OP's code (which in the example given in the question it **won't**) then you can't fix it. You're just moving other bits of code around to no practical effect. The question that was asked is, in its current state, unanswerable and your attempt to answer it is just a red herring.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you mean. Anyways the XHR request needed some serious revisiting so I couldn't resist! :D

Comment: This is not work for me. i use `document.getElementById('a_pageLength_{!! $id !!}').value = '0';` out of xmlhttprequest, it is work correctly. That mean element not null but when i used inside of xmlhttprequest give me null @MattiaRasulo

Comment: Yes you were out of context. In fact in my code I select the element in the global context.